# Trying to remove post thumbnail with plugin

Tags: php, post-meta, thumbnails

I have a plugin that need to remove the post thumbnail under certain conditions. Tried to hook to "get_post_metadata" filter but the code doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
public function helper() {
    ...
    add_filter('get_post_metadata', array($this, 'removeThumbnail'), 999, 4);
    ...
}

public function removeThumbnail($metadata, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {
    return ( isset($meta_key) && '_thumbnail_id' === $meta_key ) ? false : $metadata;
}
```

My class is initialized on the_content hook.

However, it doesn't remove the featured image in the post. Any insights and ideas how to make it happen?

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean???? Please file an [edit] and ***PROPELY*** explain what your **exact** issue is.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. It doesn't remove the featured image in the post.

Comment: Are you getting error, how are you initialising your class, etc etc. I again ask, file an [edit] with all of this info. Important info **must** be inside your question, and not in a comment

Answer (score 1):

I found where the problem was. The code was attached to the **`the_content`** hook which runs after the thumbnail is generated.

Attached the code to **`post_thumbnail_html`** and it works now.